# Ionic build : Error: spawn EACCES and Subproject Path: CordovaLib

Tags: build, ionic2

```
ANDROID_HOME=/root/Android/Sdk

JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_131
```

Subproject Path: `CordovaLib`

Error: `spawn EACCES`

Answer (score 3):

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android
```

If it doesn't work run before

```
chmod -R 755 ~/Library/Android
```

and again the above commands